# Drupal 7 Theme [Business] not pulling in to non-front pages

Tags: theming

I am programming five custom modules for a client in Drupal 7.  Tey have, well, **HAD**, a company in India doing their front-end work.  *Something* went wrong and the India company stopped responding and developing the front end, so I have been tasked with finishing the pages and of course still complete the modules.  Didn't think this would be a real big deal, but here is the rub--

The company created the front page template.  I went in created a few pages, [ie about, connect, meet the authors, etc].  When I looked at the pages, they looked awful, no formatting at all, except for the top navbar/header which is actually pulling from the subtheme.  I have enough css skills to realize these new pages are not calling the base theme, in this case, they are using the drupal business theme located here [https://www.drupal.org/project/business].

The former company created a subtheme, of sorts, off the "Drupal Business" theme and have the page--front and page.tpl.php along with css and js related folders and files.

i turned on devel_themer and see the front/home page is calling the new front-page template. When I look and click on the body/node of my new pages below the top nav/header, the function call reference "theme-field", not the base theme or the subtheme that is in /sites/all/themes....

Since I am more a programmer and hence the reason I love Drupal, don't have to worry about all the theming stuff.  I just need the new pages to apply the base theme's css and reference the settings correctly.

Could any of the theming pro's give me some insight, assistance please?  It seems like there is a setting to apply the theme to the pages you want, but I can't figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want page specific theme'ing, look at [themekey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module:

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional
>   properties exposed by other modules.

Comment: I am willing to try anything now.  Let me give it shot.

Answer (score 0):

Does the child theme have `base theme = theme_name` defined in the .info file?

Does the child theme have an `html.tpl.php` file? If it does, does it contain the following inside the `<head>` element:

```
<?php print $head; ?>
<title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
<?php print $styles; ?>
<?php print $scripts; ?>
```

Failing that you can install the [Theme developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module to tell you which files are being used to render the page.

Comment: The child theme does contain base theme = business in the info file, but it does not have the html.tpl.php.

Comment: Looks like you need to use Theme developer to get an idea of what files are being used. You could also try using the Business theme just to make sure it's ok too

Comment: Hi Colin - Your reference to Theme developer is that the same as devel_themer that I am currently using?

Comment: Yes it's the same module